# I am trying to fetch multiple values query from Firestore am i doing it right?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I used hashmap to get the data from Filter data fragment that the user wants
to display, and I want to build a dynamic Firestore fetch query, but  I'm
not sure if this is the right way to do it.

I'm new to firestore query but I’ve tried to setup build a dynamic query by store the variables into the query using foreach, in the code explain I transform this code

```
Query filterQuery= db.collection("Property").
 .whereEqualTo("noBathrooms", "5")
 .whereEqualTo("noRooms", "2");
```

**to this.**

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : list.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue().toString();
        filterQuery=propertyRef.whereEqualTo(key,value);
    }
```

**here where I setup the query**

```
public void filterData(){

    Query filterQuery =null;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : list.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue().toString();
        Log.i(key,value);
        filterQuery=propertyRef.whereEqualTo(key,value);
    }
    dataFetch(filterQuery,R.id.rentRV);
}
```

**and here where i am bulidng it**

```
private void dataFetch(Query query,int rvView){

  FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Property> options = new 
  FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Property>()
        .setQuery(query, Property.class)
        .build();

  mAdapter = new DiscoverAdapter(options);
  RecyclerView recyclerView = root.findViewById(rvView);
  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
  LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
  recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  mAdapter.startListening();
  mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener((documentSnapshot, position) -> {
    Property property = documentSnapshot.toObject(Property.class);
    String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    mBundle.putString("id", id);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

});
}
```

Comment: You better ask google ..